# Python Script - Directory Creation Using CSV

Tags: python, automation

I am Trying to create a python script to make directory using CSV file. But I am getting - ['name'] this kind of name after, the folder has been created and some weird symbols.what should I do???

```
import csv
import os

f=open("names.txt")
csv_f=csv.reader(f)
for row in csv_f:
    os.mkdir(str(row))
```

names.txt contains

ABC

ASD

names.csv contains

ABC

ASD

Folder Name
['ASD']

Comment: You should post the code you are using so that we can be more helpful.

Comment: Please follow the question guideline. If you want help here, we'll need to see what you're working on. We can't say "why its not working" without seeing what code you're trying to run. Please post some snapshot of the CSV file you're parsing, and the code you wrote to create the directories.

Comment: sorry I'll add the code

Answer (score 0):

using `csv.reader()`, each row is returned as a list of strings, e.g. ['ASD'].  Applying `str()` to that returns "['ACD']", so os.mkdir() creates a directory with that name.

It's not clear why you are using `csv`; just use the text file. Something like this should work:

```
f=open("names.txt")

for row in f:
    os.mkdir(row.strip())

f.close()
```

or better yet:

```
with open("names.txt") as f:
    for row in f:
        os.mkdir(row.strip())
```

Comment: Getting an error saying syntax is incorrect. OSError:[WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'ABC\n'

Comment: When I use only one name it works. Like ABC only

Comment: @dArk_neutron, need to use `.strip()` to trim the whitespace from the names.  Code corrected.